# Generic .ashx for concurrent HTTP requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have created a .ashx file that is able to handle concurrent http requests.

Works great, but now I'd like to create a base class that does the common work in order to not repeat myself each time I need to create a new .ashx of the same kind.

Here is my current code for the http handler:

```
public class BaseAsyncHandler : IHttpAsyncHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public BaseAsyncHandler()
    {
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
    {
        BaseAsynchOperation asynch = new BaseAsynchOperation(cb, context, extraData);
        asynch.StartAsyncWork();
        return asynch;
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

```
public class BaseAsynchOperation : IRequiresSessionState, IAsyncResult
{
    private bool _completed;
    private Object _state;
    private AsyncCallback _callback;
    public HttpContext _httpContext;

    bool IAsyncResult.IsCompleted
    {
        get { return _completed; }
    }

    WaitHandle IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    Object IAsyncResult.AsyncState
    {
        get { return _state; }
    }

    bool IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public BaseAsynchOperation(AsyncCallback callback, HttpContext context, Object state)
    {
        _callback = callback;
        _httpContext = context;
        _state = state;
        _completed = false;
    }

    public void StartAsyncWork()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(StartAsyncTask), null);
    }

    protected virtual void OnBeforeStartAsyncTask()
    {  
    }

    public void StartAsyncTask(Object workItemState)
    {
        OnBeforeStartAsyncTask();

        _httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";


        _completed = true;
        _callback(this);
    }
}
```

My new test that inherits from the base class:

```
public class TestAsyncHandler : BaseAsyncHandler
{
    public TestAsyncHandler()
    {

    } 
}

public class TestAsyncOperation : BaseAsynchOperation
{
    public TestAsyncOperation(AsyncCallback callback, HttpContext context, object state) : base(callback, context, state)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnBeforeStartAsyncTask()
    {
        var test = _httpContext.Request["test"]; // code never ends up here...
    }
}
```

Since all my work is done in the `StartAsyncTask()` method (similar to `ProcessRequest()` in a regular generic handler .ashx), I thought that I add a method there which can be overridden. However, it never seems to get called.

What did I miss? Do you have any other suggestions on improvments?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are never creating an instance of TestAsyncHandler - that might be why the code in that class is not being called.  Mark BaseAsynchOperation as abstract to detect that at compile time.

Comment: Right. So any ideas on how to create a new instance of a `TestAsyncOperation` in the base `BeginProcessRequest`? I suppose that's what I need to do...

Comment: There are probably a lot of options.  You could define a protected abstract method in BaseAsyncHandler that returns a BaseAsynchOperation object.  Then in TestAsyncHandler, override it and return a TestAsyncOperation object.